# Sql использование DISTINCT

Tags: sql

Добрый день, есть запрос

```
SELECT 
  ENTRY_TIME,
  CODE,
  BEGINTIME,
  ENDTIME,
  AVG
FROM IND_B_SLOW
WHERE 
  SHOP = 128
  AND CODE = :numCode
  AND BEGINTIME >= TO_DATE('10.11.2015 11:00:00','DD.MM.RRRR HH24:MI:SS')
  AND ENDTIME  < TO_DATE('10.11.2015 12:00:00','DD.MM.RRRR HH24:MI:SS')
ORDER BY BEGINTIME DESC;
```

В выборке попадаются записи, где связка `BEGINTIME ENDTIME` повторяется, но у таких записей разный `ENTRY_TIME`, необходимо интерпретировать количество таких записей как одну.

Попробовал  копнуть в сторону `DISTINCT` и сделал так

```
SELECT DISTINCT
  ENTRY_TIME,
  CODE,
  BEGINTIME,
  ENDTIME,
  AVG
FROM IND_B_SLOW
WHERE
  SHOP = 128
  AND CODE = :numCode
  AND BEGINTIME >= TO_DATE('10.11.2015 11:00:00','DD.MM.RRRR HH24:MI:SS')
  AND ENDTIME  < TO_DATE('10.11.2015 12:00:00','DD.MM.RRRR HH24:MI:SS')
ORDER BY BEGINTIME DESC;
```

Верно ли это, и как можно сделать "правильнее"?

Comment: Что конкретно используется? К примеру, в PostgreSQL, помимо distinct, также имеется конструкция distinct on, которая отлично подойдет для решения данной задачи (ENTRY_TIME, при этом, будет взят первый попавшийся). Также, если вам "плевать" на значение ENTRY_TIME - то почему бы просто не выкинуть его из выборки?

Answer (score 1):

Группировка:

```
  SELECT min(ENTRY_TIME) ENTRY_TIME,
         CODE,
         BEGINTIME,
         ENDTIME,
         AVG
    FROM IND_B_SLOW
   WHERE SHOP = 128 
     AND CODE = :numCode 
     AND BEGINTIME >= TO_DATE('10.11.2015 11:00:00','DD.MM.RRRR HH24:MI:SS')
     AND ENDTIME  < TO_DATE('10.11.2015 12:00:00','DD.MM.RRRR HH24:MI:SS')
GROUP BY CODE, BEGINTIME, ENDTIME, AVG
ORDER BY BEGINTIME DESC;
```

Если используется MySQL, вместо min(ENTRY_TIME) можно использовать GROUP_CONCAT.

Comment: Если я правильно понял, то из двух записей с одинаковыми BEGINTIME и ENDTIME но разными ENTRY_TIME возьмется ОДНА с минимальным ENTRY_TIME ?

Comment: В группировке пропущены CODE и AVG

Comment: @Worker, конкретно в этом примере - да. Можно взять любую агрегатную функцию, какая вам нужна - минимум, максимум, среднее, количество... Или собрать все значения в группе в одно (GROUP_CONCAT)